# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 9381

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

I'm using gson to parse a json, but I got the message below. It happens one time or another, but most of the time it parses right.

```
09-17 16:58:18.190: W/System.err(16785): com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 9381
09-17 16:58:18.190: W/System.err(16785):    at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:54)
09-17 16:58:18.190: W/System.err(16785):    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:54)
09-17 16:58:18.195: W/System.err(16785):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:805)
09-17 16:58:18.195: W/System.err(16785):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:770)
09-17 16:58:18.195: W/System.err(16785):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:719)
09-17 16:58:18.200: W/System.err(16785):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:691)
09-17 16:58:18.200: W/System.err(16785):    at com.codal.whatsee.http.HttpRequest.makeRequest(HttpRequest.java:155)
09-17 16:58:18.200: W/System.err(16785):    at com.codal.whatsee.fragmentactivity.SearchFragmentActivity$SearchUserTask.doInBackground(SearchFragmentActivity.java:415)
09-17 16:58:18.200: W/System.err(16785):    at com.codal.whatsee.fragmentactivity.SearchFragmentActivity$SearchUserTask.doInBackground(SearchFragmentActivity.java:1)
09-17 16:58:18.205: W/System.err(16785):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-17 16:58:18.205: W/System.err(16785):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-17 16:58:18.205: W/System.err(16785):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-17 16:58:18.205: W/System.err(16785):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-17 16:58:18.205: W/System.err(16785):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-17 16:58:18.205: W/System.err(16785):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-17 16:58:18.205: W/System.err(16785): Caused by: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 9381
09-17 16:58:18.215: W/System.err(16785):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1413)
09-17 16:58:18.215: W/System.err(16785):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:496)
09-17 16:58:18.215: W/System.err(16785):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:416)
```

My parse below

public class WSSearchPost implements JsonSerializer,  JsonDeserializer {

```
    @Override
    public ISearchPostView deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type arg1, JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
        SearchPostView ws = new SearchPostView();

        ws.setId( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsString() );
        ws.setImage( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("image").getAsString() );
        ws.setData( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("date").getAsString() );
        ws.setText( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("text").getAsString() );
        ws.setUser( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("user").getAsInt() );
        ws.setNome( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString() );
        ws.setUserNome( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("username").getAsString() );
        ws.setPhoto( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("photo").getAsString() );
        ws.setLocation( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("location").getAsString() );
        ws.setRating( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("rating").getAsString() );
        ws.setMyRating( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("myrating").getAsString() );
        ws.setNumComments( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("numcomments").getAsString() );
        ws.setNumFollowers( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("numfollowers").getAsString() );
        ws.setNumFollowing( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("numfollowing").getAsString() );
        ws.setFollowing( jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("following").getAsString() );

        return ws;

//      return arg2.deserialize(jsonElement, ws.getClass());
    }
```

Comment: Catch the exception, dump failing json string to log.

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but is there a reason you're not just using Gson like so:    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            YourClass foo = gson.fromJson(inputString, YourClass.class);

Comment: I assume he is using it that way. He's just showing us the custom type adapter that he thinks is causing the problem

Comment: As **Anton Savin** said, you should log the string and also log the network response. I've seen errors like this usually happen when there's a server error. As for the deserialization adapter, if that's really your adapter, you can just use the gson.fromJson like **metter** suggested, there's nothing out of the ordinary that Gson cannot resolve. How often does this happen? 1 in 5 times, 1 in 10, 1 in 100?

Comment: I've already dump the json to a string log, but seems normal.
Actually, I'm using GsonBuilder to deserializer, is it better use the way the metter said?

Comment: It often happens randomly, sometimes I search for letter 'C' and I got the right result, then passed a time I search again for letter 'C' and it gives that error.

Comment: When I reduce the limit of items on mysql select, the search happens normally, I guess it may be the size of json that it's not parsing